# Java Web Service session management

Tags: java, authentication, soap, apache-axis

I am building a web service where the user will need to login and the application will need to maintain a persistent session.  I am using Apache Axis2 for client/server communication via SOAP/XML.  What would the simplest and most common way of doing this?  I know I could implement session management from scratch similarly to how a browser does it, using cookies, but I'd rather use standard Java libraries for this.  Am I correct in assuming that even though I'm using Axis2, the solution doesn't really have anything to do with Axis2 since Axis2 is basically just a way for the client/server to send messages to each other?

I've read a lot of information online about this, but there's so much information that it's hard to know where to start.  Basically I'm just looking for someone to point me in the right direction on what classes to use and so on.  I just need a simple username password authentication and session management system for a web service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, are you 100% sure you need sessions?  SOAP is happier without them.
Second, are you 100% sure you need Axis2?
Third, I think the most straightforward way to do sessions in Axis2 is the transport approach.  It's been a couple of years since I did this, but this http://wso2.org/library/3264 article seems reasonable.

Comment: It's a cash card app that needs to sync with the user's account on the server.  The user needs to login to his account, so I think I need sessions.  I've already built it around Axis2 so I'm kind of committed in that regard.  I'll take a look at that link.

Comment: Ok I've gone over my old threads to accept/upvote answers.  Yes I'm using SSL.  I've read the following link about the different types of Axis2 authentication and it seems like SOAP session scope is the most ideal for my app, rather than transport session, since I just need a short term session for one app.  Also the server app needs to be aware of what account the user is logging into.  What about JAAS authentication?  Will that work over SOAP, which is stateless?  http://www.developer.com/services/article.php/3620661/Axis2-Session-Management.htm

Comment: Good, this way more people will want to answer your questions.  Here's a blog post about using JAAS with Axis2, looks like he succeeded.  I never tried that myself. http://thejavamonkey.blogspot.com/2008/09/axis-2-kerberos-web-services-featuring.html